# What "A spreading pool..." means?

Tags: meaning

I bought "Game Master's Apprentice base deck" - RPG cards, one of them has option:

> What do you see? "A spreading pool..."

What it exactly means?
Is it still **swimming pool**, or it refers to **puddle** / something like **geyser**?

This is the entirety of the text. The game is about interpretation.

Comment: Welcome! Please use the "edit" link to add information. This is not a phrase that one finds together often; please give the context in which you found it.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the text? The rest of it probably provides important context.

Comment: Imagine a pool of liquid on the floor or the ground. If it is increasing in size because more liquid is coming into it, it will spread across a wider area. That is a spreading pool.

Comment: Thank you so much. So it refers to pool on the ground/floor. It is NOT pool where you can swim - swimming pool. I guess it also cannot exist on the wall, right?

Comment: Correct. A swimming pool cannot spread. In an RPG game, it might mean light, water, or blood. If it's light, it could be on a wall, but not if it's a liquid.

Answer (score 1):

"A spreading pool ..."  A pool of liquid that is expanding -- i.e. spreading out further.  For example, if you slowly pour water onto a counter or other flat surface, the small pool of water will expand or spread as you pour.